# Other uses of the word "politics"?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

How can the word politic(s) used besides it's general meaning, that is " the activities of governments concerning the political relations between countries".

For example, what does politics mean in the following sentence:

> (A man is talking a about a woman in court) She's gonna score some points concerning her husband's sexual
>   politics.

In this situation does politics mean "a set of beliefs"?

Comment: Did you consider reading through the various definitions of [*politics* in a dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/politics)?

Comment: @DanBron Yes, none of it applies to what I'm looking for.

Comment: That's not true, as you'd quickly find out if you read the page I linked to. The sense used in your example above is directly addressed there. And note that's just the *very first* dictionary I checked.

Comment: @DanBron I did not see your link earlier. Is it definition 1.5 that applies here?

Comment: In the spirit of "teach a man to fish", I'll leave that final determination up to you, and also tell you about a really cool tool you can use to check several dictionaries simultaneously, for the purposes of cross-checking and substantiating whatever conclusion you come to:  [OneLook](http://www.onelook.com/?w=Politics&ls=a).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In its most abstract and general sense *politics* is a reference to the power relations between any two (or more) entities. Given that the relationship of a man and a woman comprise the irreducible, fundamental unit of human social organization the politics of this relationship are primary and significant.

Historical development of the concept, from etymonline.com:

> Political (*adj*.) 1550s, "pertaining to a polity, civil affairs, or government;" from Latin politicus "of citizens or the state" (see politic (adj.)) + -al (1). Meaning "taking sides in party politics" (*usually pejorative*) is from 1749. Political prisoner first recorded 1860; political science is from 1779 (*first attested in Hume*). Political animal translates Greek politikon zoon (Aristotle, "*Politics*," I.ii.9) "*an animal intended to live in a city; a social animal*."
>
> polis (*n*.) "*ancient Greek city-state*," 1894, from Greek polis "*city, one's city; the state, citizens*," from PIE *pele- "*citadel*; *enclosed space, often on high ground*" (cognates: Sanskrit pur, puram "*city, citadel*," Lithuanian pilis "*fortress*").